# How can get google map v2 api key for teamwork

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-2

Sorry my english not good

I have a probleam with google map api  v2 key. I work with my team. and we need just a one api key for us project (android project). is it posible? or all member of my team must generate api key to run google map ?

Comment: if you are working with team work then you should generate a api key only in one sysyem among you.. And use that api key...in your projectt.

Answer (score 5):

You can share the same API key, provided that you're signing the app with the same .apk signing key.

By default the debug.keystore that is used for signing debug versions of your app is auto-generated by the tools and it's different for each installation. You'll need to share debug.keystore file between your team members and configure your tools to use it. In Eclipse it is configured in Preferences -> Android -> Build -> Custom debug keystore.

Of course, you'll need another API key for the app version signed for release.

Comment: I am also having almost same isuue..I am able to login to google in the app through build generated from my computer but if someone else from my team is generating build on his computer than he is not able to login AND WE ARE USING SAME DEBUG.KEYSTORE..I created Client ID by specifying my project package name and SHA-1 fingerprint at developer console and also created consent screen.Am i missing something on developer console?Any idea why i am facing this issue?Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

use this command to generate the SHA Key

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\DON\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

DON , my system name ok.

```
 and follow this tutorial 
 http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html


 and further  more  u want
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/
```

Comment: Use "  %USERPROFILE%  " --- 


C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android